# Garbage collection interfering with object creation?

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

I am working on a WPF application that has a DevExpress DocumentGroup in it that is holding different panels with Pages inside them. One of the Pages called 'overview' that i use has a has a very large picture (10.000 x 7.000) as a background. When I click on a button to create a new Panel that contains an overview I can see in the taskmanager how more and more memory gets used.

After I close the overview panel the memory usage goes down a bit, but never as low as it was before I opened the Page. If i open and close the page a few times the memory usage gets to a critical point at witch the programm freezes and never loads the overview. A look in the taskmanager shows, that the memory usage went drastically down.

Shouldn't the garbage collector delete the instances of my overview as soon as I close and therefore delete all the references to my overview? Does the garbage collector decide to 'collect' while I am in the middle of the process of creating a new overview page and therefore interrupting the creation?

Comment: Which version of .net?

Comment: *After I close the overview panel the memory usage goes down a bit, but never as low as it was before I opened the Page* - it is normal behaviour because garbage collector doesn't collects memory right after you're closing your panel. And are you sure you have no more references to your overview that can prevent GC from collection it? It can be verified using some memory profilers.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I am using .Net 4.0

Comment: @AndyKorneyev could you recommend me a memory profiler that I could use to check that?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev After thinking about it; Isn't the freed memory after the supposedly collected 'garbage' a sign that the collector freed the memory? The application is still running, it doesn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: @KArlk. well, I've used [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) and find it convinient. It is not free, but there is 14-days trial version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's biting you is this portion from [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#generations)

> Ordinarily, the large object heap is not compacted, because copying
>   large objects imposes a performance penalty. However, starting with
>   the .NET Framework 4.5.1, you can use the
>   `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode` property to compact the large
>   object heap on demand.

So your image is immediately promoted to the Gen 2 object pool, and what's more is added to the large object heap. When the collector is running in *workstation* mode (the default for Windows 7, 8 etc machines, it's *server* for the Windows Server editions) then these objects will never be collected or compacted.
I'm pretty sure that forcing a `GC.Collect()` will do absolutely nothing for you, because the collector (in workstation mode) will ignore the large object heap.

I've seen this testing a heavy message processing service on a Windows7 machine, after a couple of 100k messages the app would terminate with an out of memory exception. **Switching the collector to server mode fixed the issue for me.**

From the MSDN entry [`<gcServer>` Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357(v=vs.110).aspx):- Add this to your project's app.config file

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Update**
OK, remove the finalizer, that's not what it's for and it will have either no effect or a negative effect on garbage collection.

Calling CG.Collect() will not guarantee that you'll see memory usage go down, the Collector is a complicated beast and predicting what it will do in any given situation is a fools errand.

There are pretty much only two things you can do at this stage, and you'll probably need to do both.

1. Ensure there are no references to the large object, including
   event handlers listening for events raised by that object.
2. Run it through a memory profiler, like ANTS mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: I added your code, but unfortunatly I get the same results. Does this work with .Net 4.0 or only with .Net 4.5.1? I also added 'GC.Collect()' to the overview close function, but that didn't help either. What confuses me is the fact, that i don't get any kind of exception, the application just freezes.

Comment: I made sure that the servermode garbage collector is activated by using IsServerGC(), which returned true. If I understand correctly, now I should be able to call the GC manualy by using GC.Collect() and that should also affect the large object heap. When I call the Collect() no memory is freed. Is this a sign that there are still references to my overview somwhere hidden and therefore the garbage collector doesn't free the memory? I even added a destructor to the overview class that sets the image.Source = null.

Comment: I tried to remove all event handlers but that didn't change a thing (maybe I didn't get all of them?). However, after you told me that my destructor wouldn't work, I added a button (lets call it 'b1') that sets the image.Source = null. If I call the GC after a click on 'b1', the memory actually is freed. Strangely though if i call the same code that 'b1' executes in my other method that also deletes the whole overview object and the tab, it doesn't work. Only if i click 'b1' and after that call the other method it actually works.

Comment: I finally found the source of the problem. It was indeed an event handler that I had set in a helper class that I totaly forgot existed. It was set to listen to a Changed event on the matrixTransform that i use to scale the image. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the [MSDN about the fundamentals of GC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx), it shows the following:

Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is true:

- The system has low physical memory.
- The memory that is used by
  allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable
  threshold. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process
  runs.
- The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do
  not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs
  continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and
  testing.

So, it doesn't clear the memory right away after closing your overview, as you seem to be expecting. The GC clears the memory when it feels it needs to.

Comment: Yes, it could be the first point. That still leaves my second question open. Could the garbage collector be the reason why my application doesn't load the overview and instead freezes?

Comment: If you're creating a new instance of your overview, I don't see how there would be any kind of interuption when the GC clears up an old instance. But I could be wrong.